# How to open file browser with a specific file selected by default?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, nemo, xdg-open, caja

Let's assume a situation where I have a terminal emulator open on my GUI and I have changed my working directory to some specific directory. I know that current directory contains file `xyz`.

Is it possible to open a new file browser window with my current working directory *and* have the file `xyz` focused by default but not launched automatically?

If multiple solutions exist, I'd prefer using `xdg-open`, `caja`, `nautilus` or `nemo` with some command line flags. Basically I'm looking for command like

```
xdg-open --in-file-browser xyz
```

which obviously does not work but is there a way to make it or something similar to work?

Bonus points for having a command that allows me to open a file browser view with multiple files pre-selected so that I could write

```
xdg-open --in-file-browser *.png
```

to e.g. easily start drag and drop operation for exactly those files.

Comment: How do you feel about that answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364997/open-a-directory-in-the-default-file-manager-and-select-a-file

Comment: simply `nautilus /path/to/file` (where file is the actual file) seems to open the directory & select the file. `-s` does the same. multiple arguments does not work unfortunately.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks, it seems that nautilus does support this but `nemo` nor `caja` do not. It seems that `nautilus file1 file2` will open two windows with one of the files selected in each. Interestingly, `nautilus -s file1 -s file2` will open two `nemo` windows with one file selected in each. I guess it's possible open the window and focus the file via dbus or something and nautilus accidentally focuses the file in `nemo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that `xdg-open` does not support this. Status of some specific file browsers:

- **Caja**: no support, giving command line parameters does equivalent of `xdg-open` for each parameter.
- **Nemo**: `nemo --no-desktop FILE` will open a new window with the FILE preselected. If multiple files are given, Nemo will open a new window for each.
- **Nautilus**: `nautilus --no-desktop FILE` will open a new window with the FILE preselected. If multiple files are given, Nautilus will execute a new process `nautilus FILE1` ... `nautilus FILEx` for each parameter. Note that Nautilus will create new processes, not just open multiple windows or fork itself.

As far as I can figure out, no file browser supports opening a window with multiple files preselected.